# Rebuilding a Widget in a column

Tags: flutter

So I have 2 widgets in a column. 1 is a listview of containers and another is a Column of TabBar and TabBarView. I wrote this code which helps me store the current index is the TabView selected

```
 TabController _tabController;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
    globals.tabIndex = _tabController.index;
    });
  }
```

[image: MyApp]

As per the image I want to change the color of the tile as the active listview changes (Active container is blue). The containers have an onTap functions which changes their color as they are pressed. Is there anyway I can rebuild the top containers when the listview Index changes?

Comment: Can you share the code that build the top container ?

Comment: If you manage the content and styling of those tiles in the same class that's managing the _tabController then you can just pass those changes down and setState to rebuild the view. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call the setState function to rebuild the widget;

[image]

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Example(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _Item(
              isActive: _tabController.index == 0,
              onTap: () => _tabController.animateTo(0),
            ),
            _Item(
              isActive: _tabController.index == 1,
              onTap: () => _tabController.animateTo(1),
            ),
            _Item(
              isActive: _tabController.index == 2,
              onTap: () => _tabController.animateTo(2),
            ),
            _Item(
              isActive: _tabController.index == 3,
              onTap: () => _tabController.animateTo(3),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            _TabItem(
              'one',
            ),
            _TabItem('two'),
            _TabItem('three'),
            _TabItem('four'),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _TabItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const _TabItem(this.title, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    );
  }
}

class _Item extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isActive;
  final Function onTap;

  const _Item({Key key, this.isActive, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 50,
        color: isActive ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
        child: Text('hey'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My TabBar and Tab bar view widgets are in another dart file. I am just importing that widget to my main.dart. But it seems the class in my main.dart cannot access the _tabController which I had defined in the other dart file.                                             PS. I declared tabcontroller in main.dart and passed my TabView widget with controller as arguement and it seems to work. Thanks for the help !

Comment: When I swipe the TabBarList instead of tapping the TabBar, the index changes very slowly and there is a delay in the animation of the top containers. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Add your code, and I'll check it. You can send me by email kherel@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Hey there created a simple example to show how you would achieve this. Uses all the components you mentioned, tabBar, TabBarView, ListViewBuilder to create the list.

And onTap of the element use the tabController to animate to the Tab. And this subsequently trigger the addListener callaback  which updates the currentSelected Index.

https://dartpad.dev/5f5475b790fe9a75b26c1f686adab96e